# Idiomatic way of conditionally computing a value and borrowing into struct in Rust

Tags: rust

Consider the following function that creates a new user with an optional `user_uuid`. We may or may not have a `user_uuid` specified in advance, therefore we need to fill the field ourselves if it is missing.

```rust
pub struct User<'a> {
    pub user_uuid: Option<&'a str>,
    pub email: String,
}

pub async fn create_user<'a>(db: &SqlitePool, u: User<'a>) -> Result<(), sqlx::Error> {
    let uuid = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();

    let user = User {
        user_uuid: Some(u.user_uuid.unwrap_or_else(|| &uuid)),
        ..u
    };
...
}
```

I'm trying to work out the most idiomatic rust way of solving this problem, (and definitely prematurely optimising in the process - but this is a helpful way to learn).

One possible solution is above, but it does yield an expensive UUID creation on every call of the function. My rationale here is that if the UUID isn't generated at the top of the function, conditionally creating it yields an object that doesn't live long enough - because it'll be scoped to the `if` statement and thus can't be borrowed outside. Another method I found was to pattern match the UUID as a `String` and then borrow it immediately after in the struct initialiser.

How could I solve this problem without:

1. Unnecessary redundant computation
2. Without unnecessary allocations or copies.

Thank you!

Comment: Why is `user_uuid` not a `Option<Uuid>`?

Comment: My backing database is sqlite, and in general I'd just like it to be some string variant. But agree that might be wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sticking point here is getting the string to outlive `user` but creating it in the `unwrap_or_else` closure.

This is actually pretty easy. Just declare a mutable `String` variable and assign to it in the closure, returning a reference to it:

```
let mut uuid = String::new();

let user = User {
    user_uuid: Some(u.user_uuid.unwrap_or_else(|| {
        uuid = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();
        &uuid
    })),
    ..u
};
```

Note that `String::new()` doesn't allocate.

Answer (score 1):

As complement to cdhowie's answer, you don't even need to initialise the outer uuid (and make it mut) if you use control flow the compiler has insight into e.g.

```
let uuid;
let user = User {
    user_uuid: Some(if let Some(uuid) = u.user_uuid {
        uuid
    } else {
        uuid = String::new();
        &uuid
    }),
};
```